# To Make an API Centric Application or Not? - Laravel

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest, laravel

So. I have embarked on the journey of learning Laravel in the last couple of weeks, and am thoroughly enjoying it.

It has come time for a site redesign and I thought it was about time to tighten up some of our functionality, so I am making the switch from CodeIgniter to Laravel.

I was wondering whether it is worth starting off with a RESTful API layer in Laravel (easy enough to create) and use it as a base even for the web application. In the future we are likely to build a mobile app that will need to use the API. So:

1. Is it worth having the web application connect to the API
2. and what is the easiest way/s to make calls to the API without having to write a bazillion
   lines for cURL everytime I want to make a request?

Comment: Just an addition to this - try using Guzzle (http://guzzlephp.org/) to send and receive requests with PHP, it's a lovely wrapper around Curl and will save you writing loads of curl requests, example: `$client = new Guzzle\Http\Client('http://example.com'); $response = $client->get('/api/users')->send()`. Really useful!

Comment: Thought I'd post this relevant link, as I pass on through web searching land.  Aaron Kuzemchak's presentation at Laracon 2013 (Laravel Conference), "Simple API Development With Laravel."
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xa-FRWDxJrI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely worth it.

I am currently redesigning a messy PHP code for an established hosting company turning it into beautiful Laravel code. I already have a mobile app working with it - Laravel makes it easy to return JSON data with one line -

```
Response::json('OK', 200);
```

or

```
Response::eloquent(Auth::user());
```

or

```
$tasks = Task::all();
Response::eloquent($tasks);
```

You don't need to use CURL as far as I know. 
You can make all requests with simple AJAX, jQuery would simplify that.

Also using some MVC JS framework would help you make the application code structure more elegant for the client side, and the advantage is that you can easily package that into PhoneGap when you are ready to have your API take some real testing.

Today I posted on my blog about a simple example that you can try to see if this approach is worth your time : http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/login-to-laravel-web-application-from-phonegap-or-backbone/

Check it out and accept the answer if you think it's on the right track.

Comment: Hey mate. I read you blog regularly. Thanks a lot for the answer. I was wondering though, let's say I have setup the API in Laravel, would I then make a layer on top of that to interact with the API for the web app? For example, I have a controller that displays the home page and lists a bunch of database results. How would I interact with the API server side to achieve this?

Comment: Max, I am accepting your answer as it put me on the right track. I have started using cURL to connect PHP to the API I have built in Laravel. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can do CURL but it probably is somewhat easier to make a client-side application that loads things from the server-side API.

Comment: Oh so you mean using something like javascript (client-side) to interact with the api? Rather than cURL in php?

Comment: +1 Also the answer to my question. Thanks a lot also for your blog post.

Comment: @Sneaksta yes you can use AJAX for example using Backbone JS, Ember or any other client side framework to make it easy to work with Backend API. This will simplify a lot of things for you in a small-medium scale application and make lots of code reusable in the future apps.

Answer (score 1):

As always, your results may vary, but this is exactly what I'm going through at the moment. I'm migrating a large .Net site with this API architecture and I've decided to keep it for Laravel.

I personally decided for this because:

1. More scalable. I can setup api.domain.com and then add additional
   boxes/vm/whatever as our traffic grows. In fact, you could load
   balance just the api by "round robin" or multiple dns entries for
   that domain.
2. Future proofing for new sites and apps. Sounds like you're in the
   same situation. I can see an app or two being added in the next year
   or so.
3. Lost cost. You'll already be laying out your controllers, so really
   it can be just a matter of setting them to RESTful and making small
   tweaks to accommodate.

To be fair, some counter points:

1. Possibly additional load time, from processing through the API, though this should be minimal.
2. Additional security items to consider if you'd like to lock things down to just your app.

Either way, welcome to Laravel!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the welcome! :) Very good points to consider.

Answer (score 0):

> > and what is the easiest way/s to make calls to the API without having to write a bazillion lines for cURL everytime I want to make a request?

@Sneaksta try postman chrome extension for calling rest services. you can create forms in this extension and pass data from these forms to you Rest services
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon